# How to install webpacker inside rails Engine?

Tags: webpack, hadoop-yarn, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-engines, webpacker

I have built one Rails Engine using rails 6.0.3.2 as by default webpacker is not present inside the engine so I have configured the webpacker manually using https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/engines.md  link.
But when I am trying to do rails app:webpacker:compile the error is

Compilation failed:
yarn run v1.19.1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

error Command "webpack" not found.
How can I configure Webpacker inside my rails engine?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is something the rails community has been struggling with for several years now. https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/348

Comment: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/engines.md